# How can i search with xpath selector both by text and by class

Tags: jquery, xpath

I am trying to reach an element with xpath by matching the element class and the content.

let's say that this is the query for the class `//span[contains(@class, "text")]`.

and this is the query for the content `//span[text()[contains(., "Page")]]`.

but is there anyway i can make one query with both queries?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`and`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp) to combine both predicates as below:

```
//span[contains(@class, "text") and text()[contains(., "Page")]]
```

Comment: @anderson just curious: isn't the 'text()[...]' redundant since contains(.,"Page") is already searching text? Would //span[contains(@class, 'text') and contains(.,'Page')] return the same thing?  Not nit-picking, just trying to learn myself.

Comment: @anderson nevermind, I looked on your profile and saw you had yourself posted a question along that line and the answers provided were sufficient.  Because you don't know the exact layout of the HTML using text() is more specific referencing the text node only, while "." might work, but refers to the current node, which might not be what you think it is (in a nutshell)